# Wireguard on Ubuntu and ios client

Tags: wireguard

I setup Wireguard on a Linode server using Ubuntu. That seems all fine. However, when I use the instructions to create a QR code for my iOS client, and I connect I don't show my server ip in whatsmyip and I cannot ping 10.1.1.2.

These were my server setup instructions:

https://graspingtech.com/self-host-vpn-linode/

This was my instructions for getting a QR code for ios setup:

https://wireguard.how/client/ios/

my server config:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.1.1.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = ######
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = 4AMSp8z8jqUpF0N4cfFZGeDeJW66S+n/CG8dbDrRkjg=
AllowedIPs = 10.1.1.2/32
```

My phone:

```
[interface]
Addresses: 10.1.1.1/24

[peer]
Public Key -- is correct
Endpoint -- my Linode ip
Allowed IPs 10.1.1.2/32
On-demand is off
```

If I do wg show on my server, it looks like there is a connection handshake working properly. Shouldn't whatsmyip show as my server for my iPhone when connected?

Comment: What configuration is on your client?  You haveo to set `0.0.0.0/0` on the client config's Allowed IPs to set the route such that everything goes over the Wireguard line.

Comment: Should I add this to the server config? When I add it to the iOS config I can't get to any website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much experience with WireGuard and Linode, but having just finished our own setup, I wonder if you followed the client instructions from the first how-to or the second. Because the second one talks about a different subnet, from what I can see. **10.0.2.2** vs **10.1.1.2**. Are you sure you set it properly there?

If you followed the first instructions, even for the iOS client, you should be able to set it up correctly. If you want all traffic to go through WireGuard, make sure to set the client to "**AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0**".

Update: I don't see any DNS servers on the '[interface]' part. Could that be why you don't have any success with 0.0.0.0/0?

Also, you set your phone to the same IP as the server.

Can you try this for your phone?

```
[interface]
Addresses: 10.1.1.2/24
DNS = 8.8.8.8

[peer]
Public Key -- is correct
Endpoint -- my Linode ip
Allowed IPs 10.1.1.0/24
On-demand is off
```

Comment: I tried you suggestion to add 0.0.0.0/0 and I couldn't connect to the internet at all I'm editing my question with my wg0.conf

Comment: ok, adding the dns for 8.8.8.8 allowed me to use it and it is reporting the right ip of my linode server. Thanks. Is there a good document for setting up multiple clients?

Comment: @bradrice It's as simple as adding a new peer section with its own pubkey.  Make sure each peer section has only one /32 IP on there for alloweed IPs or you'll have some routing issues.  I can pull an example config on one of my servers and share with you, give me a few to grab it.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I wish someone wrote up documentation that is simple to follow